# SQL Server:.- group multiple columns by SUM of ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sum, pivot

I have the following table on a SQL Server 2016 database

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT [ID]
      ,[comb_date]
      ,PARSE(comb_date AS datetime USING 'en-GB') as comb_date_dt
      ,[ICC_NAME]
FROM [GC].[dbo].[TABLE1]


ID      comb_date       comb_date_dt            ICC_NAME
89767   1/07/2000 4:07  2000-07-01 04:07:00.000 Wangaratta
42280   1/07/2000 4:13  2000-07-01 04:13:00.000 Geelong
25238   1/07/2000 17:28 2000-07-01 17:28:00.000 Dandenong
38419   1/07/2000 22:18 2000-07-01 22:18:00.000 Ferntree Gully
11222   1/07/2000 23:06 2000-07-01 23:06:00.000 Bendigo
47337   2/07/2000 0:17  2000-07-02 00:17:00.000 Gisborne
25239   2/07/2000 0:43  2000-07-02 00:43:00.000 Dandenong
38420   2/07/2000 2:03  2000-07-02 02:03:00.000 Ferntree Gully
66686   2/07/2000 2:57  2000-07-02 02:57:00.000 Leongatha
38421   2/07/2000 8:57  2000-07-02 08:57:00.000 Ferntree Gully
25240   2/07/2000 12:20 2000-07-02 12:20:00.000 Dandenong
11223   3/07/2000 14:26 2000-07-03 14:26:00.000 Bendigo
11224   3/07/2000 14:29 2000-07-03 14:29:00.000 Bendigo
47338   3/07/2000 15:54 2000-07-03 15:54:00.000 Gisborne
42281   3/07/2000 17:03 2000-07-03 17:03:00.000 Geelong
23147   3/07/2000 18:40 2000-07-03 18:40:00.000 Colac
59198   4/07/2000 13:15 2000-07-04 13:15:00.000 Heywood
25241   4/07/2000 14:39 2000-07-04 14:39:00.000 Dandenong
38422   4/07/2000 17:12 2000-07-04 17:12:00.000 Ferntree Gully
25242   4/07/2000 20:59 2000-07-04 20:59:00.000 Dandenong
...
...
...    30/06/2018 22:30 2018-06-30 22:30:00.000 ORBOST
```

The table shows all incidents from July 2000 to June 2018 for every ICC_NAME. There are about 30 unique ICC_NAME values.

What I would like to get is an output which has year-month (from 2000-07 to 2018-06) as rows (dt_yyyy_mm), each ICC_NAME as column and monthly count / sum of numbers records for each year-month and ICC_NAME.

```
dt_yyyy_mm    Dandenong    Ferntree Gully    Heywood    Geelong    Gisborne ... ...    Wangaratta
2000-01       21           9                 14         27         6        ... ...    16
2000-02       17           11                20         4          15       ... ...    19
... ...
2018-06       13           7                 9          11         2        ... ...    13
```

I assume I will need to use multiple "group" on the records and by sum of IDs 
 for each yyyy-mm and ICC_NAME respectively, but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know in advance the list of `icc_names`, you can use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select
    format(comb_date, 'yyyy-MM') dt_yyyy_mm,
    sum(case when icc_name = 'Dandenong' then 1 else 0 end) Dandenong,
    sum(case when icc_name = 'Ferntree Gully' then 1 else 0 end) Ferntree_Gully,
    ...
from [GC].[dbo].[TABLE1]
group byormat(comb_date, 'yyyy-MM')
order by dt_yyyy_mm
```

Answer (score 0):

Can not be done without dynamic SQL and 2 statements. What you look for is the PIVOT statement, but PIVOT needs to have the new columns defined IN THE SQL. Which means you can not dynamically get them - you FIRST need to get all columns, then create the SQL Statement for the PIVOT an then issue that with Execute SQL (or from your application).